# Keeping sealed lead acid battery bank in good condition - and science behind

Tags: lead-acid, solar-charge-controller

I will have 2 lesuire batteries on the boat. The bank will be 12 V and 150 or 220 Ah (not sure yet). **I am trying to find out if constantly delivering low current (say 0.1) before charged and later trickle charging with very little current, just to keep them full, will prevent batteries from sulfation and will keep them happy for several years?** I see that they should be fully charged after use by 'normal' charger, but I will not have such possibility. The only mean for charging will be solar panel (40 W) with proper controller, and I am afraid it will often work on limited power due to weather or shade (nothing I can do about it). They will charge eventually on good days, but it will take some time. However, I am not planning to use much of them - probably never more than 50% of their capacity.

Comment: No, check out the life of batteries used for UPS. They get replaced every few years. Batteries last longer if they are exercised - all of this you can find through research….

Comment: As you say "will have", perhaps it is not too late to look at LFP with proper LFP charging to match. With these, you certainly won't want (or need) low current trickle charging. Just topup and if necessary rebalance every 3-6 months. Much more likely to last years with much less degradation.

Answer (score 1):

Lead-acid batteries don't like being overcharged.  In general, they're charged with a 3-stage charging process: a constant-current phase, driving as much current as is available from the charger, or that the batteries can take, whichever is less; then a constant-voltage "topping" charge which is nominally 2.3V per cell, but if you're fancy it varies by battery temperature; then finally a lower-voltage "float" charge which is nominally 2.2V per cell, but that also varies with temperature and opinion.

You want to build or buy a battery charger that can automatically handle this.

I can't help you with the shopping part of this -- I'm sure there's systems out there that range from a resistor and a hunk of scrap iron inside an expensive-looking case, to a really well-thought-out charge management system that actually works and keeps batteries alive for as long as possible.  The way that *I* would know what to get would be to hit the appropriate boating publications and forums, find out what people are using, and compare that to your use case.  If you talk to someone you can trust who has the same sort of system you has, *and* who sees their batteries last a good long time do what any good engineer does and shamelessly copy their system.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you very much for your answer. So I asked on boating forums and general consensus is 'its fine', but I would like to ask on specialists forums as I want to understand the science.
I wasn't precise - I will update my answer - I will use charge controller that will controll that batteries are charged as you described - so batteries when fully charged will get very little current, and I wonder how the constant, tiny amout of current to keep charge is affecting battery life.

Comment: You may want to edit your question further to say that you're using a charge controller.  Just shoving in a constant current is bad; holding the battery at a constant float voltage is good.  _If_ the controller is holding a constant float voltage, then that tiny current needed to hold it is counteracting the battery's tendency to self-discharge, and holding it at the ideal fully charged state.

Comment: Third stage may be measuring voltage with zero charge current and repeating second stage when voltage drops under 2.2V.